# How do I use word boundaries in the RegExp object

Tags: javascript, regex, word-boundary

What I want to know is how do I use word boundaries in the RegExp object.

For example:

```
var reg = new RegExp("\bAB\b", "g");
```

This is not working and I can't do:

```
var reg = /\bAB\b/g;
```

Since I will need to replace the AB with a variable later on.

I know all of the other things work in the RegExp object but for some reason word boundaries don't work. Thanks for any help on this issue. :)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7Kt5A/1/

Comment: This seems to be Javascript, so I'll tag it.

Comment: `"shdfkjABdsfk AB sdkfjh sdf AB".match(/\bAB\b/g)` works for me in the Developer Console (Safari).

Comment: UmI said that the object way isnt working

Comment: This doesnt work: http://jsfiddle.net/7Kt5A/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Escape your backslashes with backslashes so the `\b` isn't interpreted as an escape character, but rather as a literal `\b`.

```
var reg = new RegExp("\\bAB\\b", "g");
reg.test(' AB ');
// true
reg.test('aABb');
// false
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need a couple of extra backslashes

```
var reg = new RegExp("\\bAB\\b", "g");
```

Since it's a string, and a backslash escapes the following character, you'll have to escape the backslashes themselves.